# Subscript assignment overloading

Tags: c++, c++11

I have created a `class Poly` in **C++**, which has the private members as defined below.

```
private:
 std::size_t sz;
 std::vector  <T>  elem;
```

What is the standard way of overloading assignment operator and/or subscript operator to assign value to an element of a container? For example:

```
  Poly < double > obj{1, 2, 3};
  obj[1] = 1;
```

should assign the value 1 to the second element.

One way to implement this maybe:

```
 T & operator[](int i) {
   if(i < 0 || i >= sz)
     throw std::out_of_range{"Poly::operator[]"};
   return elem[i];
 }
```

However, this returns the element by reference and the assignment is done outside the class, as opposed to being done by a member function. Does it not violate the principle of *abstraction* as the private members are being accessed outside the object? Moreover, one cannot ensure the checking of the *invariants*, i.e., let's say we had a restriction on the value that could be assigned.

I would rather prefer having a member function such as:

```
void assign_val(T val, int idx)
{
//Check if the conditions hold...
//...
elem[idx]=val;
}
```

For subscript reading:

```
  const T & operator[](int i) const{
   if(i < 0 || i >= sz)
     throw std::out_of_range{"Poly::operator[]"};
   return elem[i];
 }
```

Can something to this effect be obtained using operator overloading?

Comment: You should make the vector elements be a class, then you can overload the assignment operator to check the values.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking to create a class/struct (let's say class ValType) inside the class Poly and then the vector elem should hold values of type ValType. When the operator [] is used, I should then return the class and let operator= take care of the assignment? Is it similar to use of proxy class as  in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7411385/2674424 ?

Comment: Yes, that looks similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve that. By using operators you have to expose a reference to the variable if you want to assign a value to it. There is no function call involved in this process, it is being held by providing place in memory where the value is actually stored.